# Drupal 7 db_select nested select query

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

How to convert nested select queries to Drual 7 db_select? Following is the problem query:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    tbl_word 
where 
    EngWord like '%apple%' or 
    WordID in (
        select 
            WordID 
        from 
            tbl_subword 
        where 
            EngWord like '%apple%'
    );
```

Comment: see http://thanhnp.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/write-a-sub-query-by-db_select-drupal7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semantically it's pretty simliar:

```
$term = 'apple';

$sub_query = db_select('tbl_subword')
  ->fields('tbl_subword', array('WordID'))
  ->condition('EngWord', '%' . db_like($term) . '%'), 'LIKE');

$query = db_select('tbl_word')
  ->fields('tbl_word')
  ->condition(db_or()
    ->condition('EngWord', '%' . db_like($term) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->condition('WordID', $sub_query, 'IN')
  );

$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Would that not produce an AND in the main query, I think he's needing to OR the term with the subquery?

Comment: Great! Its working correctly. just fix extra braket on condition which is causing parse error.